# Books and tutorials on Windows Services in C#?

Tags: windows-services

What are some good resources for creating/implementing Windows Services i.e.( books and/or tutorials ). What do people usually use for reference? Is there a simple step by step resource that could be easily used?

Comment: And here we go again, closed, by a SO old-timer, and 8 years ago, no less. Good luck,  everyone!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There aren't many books because writing a Windows Service in C# is quite trivial. There isn't much more to it than [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2005/03/15/396428.aspx).

The Windows Service code should just be a thin layer to bootstrap the functionality you wish to expose as a service.

For the same reason you don't find many books on writing console applications in C#.

Comment: what about when no user is logged in, what about registry access, what about impersonation of users rights, etc.